# Is there a tool to optimize flows/validate flows

Tags: visual-workflow

Salesforce is investing heavily on Flows. This will allow anyone to develop apps faster (low code platform). Also, this Dreamforce they announced that they will discontinue process builder.

My Concern: In Apex we have test classes to check the code coverage and validate code logic (used in regression testing). Do we have such similar tools for Flows, as otherwise flow can grow into a village in itself which will be difficult to manage, track and optimize. From maintainability perspective, I think it could be a nightmare.

What do you think ? Is there any tool, I am not aware of...

Comment: What is the reason you do not see Apex testing as a viable "tool" to test your Flows? At the end of day, you're performing data manipulation causing the database to change therefore can be asserted using Apex system classes.

Comment: I have used apex test classes for testing Apex Classes only, yet. I know, we can test flows as well via test classes. But is that the right tool. Does Salesforce enforce coverage limitations on flows as well?

Comment: One more thing, For eg. for Lightning Pages, we have "Page Analyzer" tool to analyze even custom lightning components. Do we have something similar for flows (don't say debugger) ? 
P.S: I have not worked on flows extensively.